# is there any way to synchronise a row from an excel sheet to another one without using VB code?

Tags: excel

Is there any easy way to synchronise a row from an excel sheet where the first column on one sheet equal the value from another column in another sheet without using VB code?  The value from the first column is using the command =Sheetname!Ax.
Problem is, if anyone is sorting the column from the second sheet used as reference, on the main sheet data won't be sorted to follow changes on the first column.

Comment: Why don't you just use the same command for the second row so they both sync from the same source?

Comment: OP is looking for a two-way sync.  If I change a value in sheetA, it changes for sheetB.  If I change a value in sheetB, it changes for sheetA.

Comment: @E.Trauger - If that's the case, I don't think that can be done without VBA.  If they just want to make sure that all info on `Sheet1` is reflected on `Sheet2`, even with sorting done on `Sheet1`, you *could* set up a bunch of `=INDIRECT(Sheet1!A1)` and drag over/down on `Sheet2`.  But depending on the size of the worksheet, that may not be feasible.

Comment: I agree that it can't be done, without creating a circular reference, which wouldn't work.  I included VBA code below

Answer (score 0):

One possibility found online which *does* use VBA is as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Const COL1 = "A:A" 'amend column on sheet 1 to suit
Const COL2 = "B:B" 'amend column on sheet 2 to suit
Const SH1 = "Sheet1" 'amend sheet name to suit
Const SH2 = "Sheet2" 'amend sheet name to suit (this is the other linked sheet)


Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim rngoth As Range

Select Case Sh.Name
    Case SH1
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(Sh.Range(COL1), Target)
        Set rngoth = Worksheets(SH2).Range(COL2)
    Case SH2
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(Sh.Range(COL2), Target)
        Set rngoth = Worksheets(SH1).Range(COL1)
End Select
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cell In rng
        rngoth.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = cell.Value
    Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

You just need to change a few of the constant values for your use.  This is very easy to implement.  Why do you not want to use VBA?